# How to set which folder to load with apache2 server?

Tags: apache, apache2, linode

My friend introduce me Linode and register.com, so I am playing with it now. I already get a domain name, while on my Linode server I am trying to set up a basic webpage so I can start to use it for my personal website. I'm following http://library.linode.com/hosting-website#sph_web-server to set up.

Here's the question, I made a `testsite` folder on my linode server, and a `/etc/apache2/sites-available/testsite` file which can be called at `sudo a2ensite testsite` command. (All of these are part of the tutorial.) But when I wish to switch the content for that website, I created a `testsite1` and a `/etc/apache2/sites-available/testsite1`, then I do `sudo a2ensite testsite1`, but I don't know how to let the apache read the content from my `testsite1` folder instead of `testsite` folder. The way I did that is I try `sudo a2dissite testsite`, so then the content in `testsite1` can be read. But I hope there is better way to do that. Also I've heard apache2 can handle multiple server at the same time. How to assign which server load which folder on my linux machine? (For example, if I have abc.net and efg.net, I already link both of them to my linode server, how can I let abc.net go to read the abc folder in my linux server, while the efg.net load my efg folder?) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the httpd.conf file usually found in `/etc/apache2/conf`. Then edit the httpd.conf file and look for "Document Root" setting in this file. Change it to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/testsite1` and then restart apache: `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: I can't find it in the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. I was thinking are there any 1 to 1 mapping for the site link/folder link that can be set.

Comment: You did not read my answer. The file you are looking for is `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` NOT `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

Comment: I do have this file, but it's empty, also I think that only changes the default server? I wish to know how to mapping for the example I mentioned in the question (For example, if I have abc.net and efg.net, I already link both of them to my linode server, how can I let abc.net go to read the abc folder in my linux server, while the efg.net load my efg folder?)

Comment: Look for the line in httpd.conf that mentions the "Document Root" and change it to the directory you want. Why don't you actually read my answers and try them out? Seriously, dude. And to load different directories for different hostnames, you need to research "virtual hosts" in Apache, configuration for which is ALSO found in httpd.conf.

Comment: Any luck with your virtual hosts research?

Comment: I tried to find within my sites-available folder and found some file that contains "<VirtualHost *:80>" and "DocumentRoot" which I believe is the one I should modify. However, none of it's ServerName are the one I set for the real link name (Let's say: abc.net). I had change another file's ServerName to become abc.net but it still load the old wrong folder. And my httpd.conf is empty. Not very sure how to fix that though.

Comment: I made it, I made some mistake before, I should fix that "site-available" folder.